# Use LINQ to include items within a range

Tags: linq

I have a calendar of events. I use the following LINQ statement to load the events to display in a calendar:

```
var events = CalendarItems?.GroupBy(e => e.StartDate);
```

It results in a GroupedEnumerable with key/values like this:

```
Key = 6/26/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/10/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/18/2019, Value = CalendarItem
```

Some CalendarItems have "EndDate" and if it does, I would like each date in the range of StartDate to EndDate to also be included in the result set. So if the 7/18/2019 CalendarItem had an EndDate of 7/20/2019, then my result set would also include these 2 items:

```
Key = 7/19/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/20/2019, Value = CalendarItem
```

I have no idea how I would modify my LINQ statement. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

So, if I had these 2 CalendarItems:

```
StartDate = 7/8/2019, EndDate = null
StartDate = 7/18/2019, EndDate = 7/20/2019
```

Then my result should be:

```
Key = 7/8/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/18/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/19/2019, Value = CalendarItem
Key = 7/20/2019, Value = CalendarItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Item
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}

var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 22)},
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 12 )},
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 4, 15), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 4, 25) },
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 15), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 17) },
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 23)},
    new Item {StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 7)},
};

var x = items.Select(i => (i.StartDate, diff: Enumerable.Range(0, ((i.EndDate == null ? i.StartDate : i.EndDate).Value - i.StartDate).Days + 1)))
             .Select(x => x.diff.Select(z => x.StartDate.AddDays(z)));

var days = new List<DateTime>();
x.ToList().ForEach(dates => days.AddRange(dates));
// Output:
days.OrderBy(i => i).ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.ToShortDateString()));


/*
    Output:
    07.02.2019
    15.02.2019
    16.02.2019
    17.02.2019
    22.02.2019
    23.02.2019
    12.03.2019
    15.04.2019
    16.04.2019
    17.04.2019
    18.04.2019
    19.04.2019
    20.04.2019
    21.04.2019
    22.04.2019
    23.04.2019
    24.04.2019
    25.04.2019
*/
```

Comment: Thanks that's awesome!! I just tried your code and it got me really close to what I need. I will need to get the output into a Dictionary with the date as the key and a List<Item> as the value. If you happen to know how to do that easily, that would be great. Otherwise I should be able to figure it out tonight. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Primico Glad to help! If I have time, I'll update the code! 

Comment: @Primico Do I understand correctly that the key is always a start date? 

Comment: The keys in the dictionary can be any date. If you think of your class "Item" as an "Event"..  I can have an Event with start date of 7/25 (with no end date, it ends the same day) and another event with start date 7/25 and end date of 7/26... so the dictionary would have a key of 7/25 with 2 events and a key of 7/26 with one event.

Comment: I was able to get close but my keys are still only showing the startdates and not all dates. If you happen to have a minute and can take a look, I would really appreciate it.             var events = CalendarItems
                .Select(i => (i, diff: Enumerable.Range(0, ((i.EndDate == null ? i.StartDate : i.EndDate).Value - i.StartDate).Days + 1)))
                .Select(y => y.diff.Select(z => (y.i, y.i.StartDate.AddDays(z))))
                .ToDictionary(a => a.FirstOrDefault().Item2, a => a.FirstOrDefault().i);

Comment: @Primico I invite you to [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195595/room-for-johnyl-and-primico)...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var events = CalendarItems?.Where(x => x.EndDate.HasValue && x.StartDate < x.EndDate).GroupBy(e => e.StartDate);
```

(For the first check you could also do `x.EndDate != null`)

The biggest thing to note is just the `.Where()` clause. You could perform this when looping through the groups as well. So if you need to do the checks after the grouping, you could use this alternatively:

```
var events = CalendarItems?.GroupBy(e => e.StartDate);

foreach(var event in events)
{
    var validEvent = event.Where(x => x.EndDate.HasValue && x.StartDate < x.EndDate);
}
```

Functionally they're the same, but if for whatever reason you need to process the other dates, that `foreach()` will let you pick through what you need on a group by group basis.

Comment: Thanks. That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to include all CalendarItems. And when there is a CalendarItem with an EndDate, I want to add those additional dates into my result set.

Comment: You'd probably want to go with the `foreach()` approach then. And then add `validEvent` to your results. It might need some massaging based on the outer logic in your code, but that `where` statement will filter out items that don't have an `EndDate` and whose `StartDate` is before `EndDate`.